# Editor for EDP 7.3.2 Mac Osx 10.8.2

Tags: enthought

I am very new to python and have installed the EPD 7.3.2 academic package.

I have not been able to locate an editor for mac osx 10.8.2 within the libraries included in the package.

The only editor part of this package  is scite but this is only for Linux and Windows. The Mac version is only available for $42 through mac app store.

Thus, I was wondering how could I get an editor to run with the EPD package? Is there a specific editor that would be recognised straight after installation? Or which editor is compatible with the package.

Hope all is well,

Luc

Answer (score 1):

I work for Enthought and we have a next-generation version of EPD that is in beta. It includes a Python-centric text editor, integrated IPython prompt, package management, and many other typical features. The application is focused on the needs of scientists and engineers who are writing code in support of their work vs. the needs of full-time software development teams. That is, the intent is to keep it light-weight and easy to use with a focus on data analysis and visualization, not to compete with tools such as Eclipse or Visual Studio.

If interested, you can request access to the beta program by clicking the "EPD Reloaded" graphic on the right side of this page: http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php. The beta version currently supports Mac OS and Windows.

Regards,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

Try Textmate. It's really good for Python and a host of other languages.

It's now open source and you can get it here: https://github.com/textmate/textmate

There's also a pre-built binary: https://api.textmate.org/downloads/beta

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few free editors for Mac OSX listed here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors

I've used Editra (http://editra.org/), and had no complaints.  I never tried its PyStudio plugin, but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You should also know about Spyder, which has a Mac version available. Spyder is a scientific python editor which provides an environment similar to Matlab. Another scientific python distribution, Python(x,y), uses Spyder.  I think getting Spyder on Mac to work with EPD might be tricky, but probably worth it. It doesn't have the professional Enthought support but it has a great community.

I'm also somewhat new to python and I'm still figuring out what works best for me. I'm not surprised that Enthought is building an editor since that's one of the main features they've yet to provide - I'm really looking forward to seeing how it compares to Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) with great success  as well as [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/). I'm not sure but I would think you could also use BBEdit's free TextWrangler.

I've played around a little with the Beta Jason pointed out (though- I can't seem to find it in the current academic distributions, but maybe I'm just not looking hard enough). It will be pretty cool once deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Could try Enthought's new Canopy product, which has an IDE embedded. The CanopyExpress version requires no licensing.